# Render a new modal with slide animation when next button is pressed on previous modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations

I have created a **List.jsx** which has Start button in it

```
 <div className="container-fluid">
            <Card>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src="" />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Basic Level 1</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                the card's content.
              </Card.Text>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleShow}>Start</button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
            <ModalList showModal = {this.state.show} closeCallback = {this.handleClose}/>
          </div>
```

When Start button is pressed it loads ModalList component which will have Next button.

**ModalList.jsx**

```
<Modal show= {this.props.showModal}>
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.closeWasClicked}>
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.closeWasClicked}>
                    Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" >
                    Next
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
```

When Next is pressed I want a new Modal to get displayed with a slide animation. I don't want a separate class to be created for each modal, as the modals are many (depending on the data from API).

 I tried to search for 'how to render the same component with an animation when a button is clicked' but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Do you want to create a new modal or do you want to update the content in the <Modal.Body> once you clicked on "next"?

Comment: @grenzbotin I want to add a slide animation. So i guess a new modal would do the job